# Remove number and reference list from mime mail plaintext emails

Tags: uri, emails

Mime mail converts urls from "www.google.com" to "www.google.com [1]" in the plaintext version of email, and adds a reference list to bottom, "[1] www.google.com ". How do i remove this number and the reference list from the bottom of the plaintext email?

Edit: The mail itself has both, html and plaintext-version in itself. I want the users who view the plaintext-version of the email to not see the numbering.

Comment: Does that come from a custom module? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The mail content itself comes from a custom module implementing hook_mail. If I configure the Filter-module's text format to _not_ "Convert URLs into links", the problem disappears and the numbering is removed from plaintext email. But i want the url's to be converted into lnks in the html-version of the email. If I try to manually insert a html link to the mail (with Convert URLs into links disabled), the plain text version of the mail again contains a number with the link.

Comment: Ah OK, but plain text then means plain text. No links. You can't have links in a plain text mail so you better keep that option off or change the format to HTML then...

Comment: Yes. But the mail itself has both, html and plaintext-version in itself. I want the users who view the plaintext-version of the email to not see the numbering.

Comment: Can you add your last comment into your question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Mimemail creates the plaintext version of the mail in mimemail.inc, in the beginning of the function mimemail_html_body():

```
  if (empty($plaintext)) {
    // @todo Remove once filter_xss() can handle direct descendant selectors in inline CSS.
    // @see http://drupal.org/node/1116930
    // @see http://drupal.org/node/370903
    // Pull out the message body.
    preg_match('|<body.*?</body>|mis', $body, $matches);
    $plaintext = drupal_html_to_text($matches[0]);
  }
```

And here the `drupal_html_to_text()` creates the plaintext mail with the footnotes and the url numbering. The plaintext is created here if one is not provided already. So, the simple solution is to provide the plaintext version ourselves.

My email templates are defined by my implementation of hook_mail, as text without html (and mimemail in itself creates a html version of my emails, and in the above function, creates again a plaintext version of the mail, with the footnotes and url-numbering). So, I can provide a plaintext version of the email in my implementation of hook_mail_alter:

```
    function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) { 
        $message['params']['plaintext'] = drupal_html_to_text(implode("\r\n\r\n", $message['body'])); 
}
```

(The `$message['body']` is the array containing the message, with message rows as entries in the array). This might not need to be wrapped around the `drupal_html_to_text()` function, but in case i go nuts and start inserting html into my messages, that function will strip it off. If i start to write my emails in html, I need to write a custom function (almost a straight copy of the `drupal_html_to_text()` function) to create the plain text version of my mails, but without the footnotes and url numbering.

Thanks for your help, I would not have found this solution by my self.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a new implementation of `MailSystemInterface`.  You'll want to extend the `DefaultMailSystem` class.  You just need to override the `format()` method on that class.  It's that method's call to `drupal_html_to_text()` that makes that replacement.  So you'll need to copy that function to a custom function of your own and remove the part that you don't like.  Then, to get Drupal to use your new class you'll need to change the `mail_system` system variable to the name of your new class by calling variable_set or setting it in settings.php.

You'll end up with something like this in your custom module's .module file:

```
class ModulenameMailSystem extends DefaultMailSystem {
  public function format(array $message) {
    // Join the body array into one string.
    $message['body'] = implode("\n\n", $message['body']);
    // Convert any HTML to plain-text.
    $message['body'] = _modulename_drupal_html_to_text($message['body']);
    // Wrap the mail body for sending.
    $message['body'] = drupal_wrap_mail($message['body']);
    return $message;
  }
}

function _modulename_drupal_html_to_text($string, $allowed_tags = NULL) {
 // Function too long to put here but copy it from drupal_html_to_text() and remove the part that creates the footnotes; it's clearly commented
}
```

You could automatically set the new mail system when the module's enabled by putting this in your module's .install file:

```
function modulename_enable() {
  variable_set('mail_system', 'ModulenameMailSystem');
}
```

Comment: This is great, but doesn't work for me. I still want to use the mimemail_mailsystem (because i need to be able to add attachments to my emails), and not write my own mail system.

Comment: Oh, my mistake.  I didn't notice you mentioned you were using the Mime Mail module.  I haven't ever used that module so it didn't jump out at me as a module name and I thought you were using the default Drupal mailing functionality.  Glad you got it figured out.